# stamp (punch) detection in image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have many drawings in pdf like this [enter link description here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pvsm.ru%2Fimages%2F2017%2F03%2F02%2FPython-na-slujbe-u-konstruktora-ukroshaem-API-Kompas-3D.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pvsm.ru%2Fpython%2F247274&tbnid=_wCZMpRaanGZGM&vet=12ahUKEwj31tbHifrsAhUOuioKHSgRARIQMygHegUIARCiAQ..i&docid=QslAeb3j3iBgcM&w=800&h=566&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%85%20python&ved=2ahUKEwj31tbHifrsAhUOuioKHSgRARIQMygHegUIARCiAQ).
Drawings have different sizes (shape) and drawings can be horizontal or vertical. Each drawing has a stamp [enter link description here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Ftopeng.ru%2Fimages%2Fstate_standard-21-101-97%2Fimage056.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.topeng.ru%2Fstate_standard-21-101-97-ence.html&tbnid=r2_v0ks-oTWrtM&vet=12ahUKEwjb7Zy8kPrsAhXKsCoKHfZyD5QQMygCegUIARCpAQ..i&docid=ppfPQTpPxRyXhM&w=705&h=372&q=%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%85&ved=2ahUKEwjb7Zy8kPrsAhXKsCoKHfZyD5QQMygCegUIARCpAQ).

I need to get all information from the stamp using python.
I did next:

1. change document format(from pdf to jpg)
2. find a stamp, crop it
3. recognize with tesseract.

However, I did it with my hands (I look at every picture, find the absolute coordinate of the stamp), I need to do it automatically. What does it mean? My python program should find relative coordinates of the stamp and crop it.
How to find relative coordinates of stamp?
Maybe there are other methods to crop stamp (ex., find object detection, etc)

Comment: Maybe try the `pdfimages` tool (part of the Poppler suite) to extract just the images in full quality from the PDFs.

Comment: Unfortunately, a stamp is not an image, the stamp looks like mirco-table.